# Emitting Error from bottom to top through call hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following implementation where I am parsing the data first from `School` -> then `ClassRoom` and then -> `User` decoding. However, I wonder if any issues happens within the decoding or fetching procedure; how could I able to pass it all the way to ViewController. Please see `//TODO` marks in the following code

**SchoolViewController.swift**

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()

schoolVM.fetchingSchoolList() { error in
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if error == nil {
      self.schoolCollectionView.reloadData()
    } else {
      // TODO : show an alert here
    }
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  }
}
```

**SchoolViewModal.swift**

```
enum ViewModalError: Error {
  case SchoolLevelError
  case ClassroomLevelError
  case UserLevelError
}

func fetchingSchoolList(
  urlString: String = URL,
  completion: @escaping(Error?) -> ()
) {
   let operation = Operation(urlSession: URLSession(urlConfig))
   operation.dataRequest(networkRequest, successHandler: {[weak self] data in
    self?.classroomParsing(data)
    completion(nil)
   }, failureHandler: { [weak self] error in
    //TODO : SchoolLevelError
    completion(error)
    })
   } catch {
    // TODO : SchoolLevelError
     completion(error)
   }
}

private func classroomParsing(_ classroomData: Data) {
 do {
    let classroom = try decoder.decode(Classroom.self, from: classroomData)
    userParsing(classroom.userData)
  } catch {
    // TODO : error handling
    // ClassroomLevelError
 }

private func userParsing(_ userData:User) {
  do {
    let users = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: userData)
  } catch {
    // TODO : error handling
    // UserLevelError
  }
}
```

Comment: You can mark your parsing method with the `throw`. and not catch the error, but let it rethrow it.?

Comment: @Larme, could you please illustrate with a simple example?

Comment: `private func classroomParsing(_ classroomData: Data) throws  { let classroom = try decoder.decode(Classroom.self, from: classroomData); try userParsing(classroom.userData) ... }` ? I guess you do something with the unused values.

Comment: These two methods should live in different methods. I could not able to put them in the same methods, I did not put entire code here, just provided minimum code for conveying the issue.

Comment: The same for userParsing. It’s the throws at definition and not doing a do/catch local

Comment: But if I do not use try-catch, how could able to pass the root of the issue to service as a log file which I did not put into the question. `ViewModalError` enum just to inform user what type of error happened in user friendly.

Comment: Is your data JSON?  If so, use `Codable` and all of the data can be decoded at once. I would also suggest that your change your code to use a `Result` So that the error or parsed data is returned via the completion handler rather than updating your property directly (which you don't seem to do anyway; the code shown simply throws away the parsed data)

Comment: @Paulw11, I should use `users` data to update the UI, the other dataset (Classroom and School) are also important for other reasons; therefore, I ended up with this design.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have your parsing functions throw the relevant error. If parsing fails then pass the error to the completion handler.

```
func fetchingSchoolList(
  urlString: String = URL,
  completion: @escaping(Error?) -> ()
) {
   let operation = Operation(urlSession: URLSession(urlConfig))
   operation.dataRequest(networkRequest, successHandler: {[weak self] data in
    do {
        try self?.classroomParsing(data)
        completion(nil)
    }
    catch {
        completion(error)
    }

   }, failureHandler: { [weak self] error in
    //TODO : SchoolLevelError
    completion(error)
    })
   } catch {
    // TODO : SchoolLevelError
     completion(error)
   }
}

private func classroomParsing(_ classroomData: Data) throws {
 do {
    let classroom = try decoder.decode(Classroom.self, from: classroomData)
    try userParsing(classroom.userData)
  } catch {
    throw(ViewModelError.ClassroomLevelError)
 }

private func userParsing(_ userData:User) throws {
  do {
    let users = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: userData)
  } catch {
    throw(ViewModelError.UserLevelError)
  }
}
```

Comment: `//TODO : SchoolLevelError
completion(error)` how should I pass `SchoolLevelError` here?

Comment: Where do you actually parse the school data?  Wherever you detect a parse problem you can simply invoke the closure with the required error